# 駆けずり回る etymology

Tags: grammar, syntax

So I encountered the title formation in a Berserk volume. Although I can infer it means "to run around aimlessly" through context, it is not quite obvious to me what the "ずり” part implies or how is it constructed. I understand it uses　the negation literary particle "ず", but I don't understand why the implication of negation (I believe the author actually wants to say he runs around aimlessly, not negate it) and why is the り used. Is it some kind of connector?

> あっちこっちの戦場をただ駆けずり回って

Comment: Though not 100％ sure I know the verb 擦る (する) means "to scratch". It could mean "running around scratching the floor" to reinforce the idea of being worn out. If I am right here ず doesn't refer to the progressive negation of the verb but the double ticks are sometimes used to form compound words in Japanese.

Comment: for reference, 狐(きつね) -> 小狐(こぎつね)

Comment: 駆けずる is a simple compound verb that should be listed in any monolingual dictionary. I don't know why jisho.org doesn't have the entry for this. Oddly, it lists [駆けずり回る](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%A7%86%E3%81%91%E3%81%9A%E3%82%8A%E5%9B%9E%E3%82%8B) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for certain, but I think that this is actually not using the 〜ず (negative) verb form at all, but actually comes from the verb 駆けづる (aka 駆けずる) ([dictionary link](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E9%A7%86%E3%81%91%E3%81%A5%E3%82%8B)) which is a rarely-used word meaning "to run around"/"to bustle about".

As far as I can tell, nowadays this verb is mostly only used as seen here, combined with 回る to make 駆けずり回る, which arguably seems a bit redundant, but I suspect may originally have been done for emphasis (e.g. "to run *all over the place*"/"to run *around and around*") and then just sorta became the usual way of saying this in general.

I'm certainly no expert, though, so would welcome any more knowledgeable opinions.

Comment: It's definitely from かけづる.  See also [the NKD entry at Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A7%86%E5%9B%9E%E3%83%BB%E9%A7%88%E5%9B%9E-2021220) (in Japanese), which shows the pre-reform kana spelling as using the づ.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi - But the same dictionary says the following in the entry for [駆ずる・駈ずる](https://kotobank.jp/word/駆ずる・駈ずる-2021221): 歴史的かなづかいは、従来、「かけづる」とするが、語源不明のため確実ではない。あるいは「かけずる」か。

Comment: @aguijonazo, I see that other dictionaries like Kojien, Daijirin, Shin Meikai, Dajisen all use the づる spelling without any such note, so at least among lexicographers, there seems to be broad agreement. Given the conjugation forms and the existence of component verb かけずる, all the evidence rules out any chance of the ず here being some form of the negative ず.

Comment: FWIW, the first appearance of かけづる is the late 900s, when I think づ and ず were probably still phonemically distinct.  As such, I'm less favorably inclined to agree with the NKD's speculative note that this might have been かけずる originally. If the [JA Wikipedia article on 四つ仮名](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%9B%E3%81%A4%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D) is anything to go by, し・ち・ず・づ were distinct at least until 1251, when we first see kana spelling confusion between じ and ぢ.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi - An amateur etymologist might see a connection with 引きずる, but it seems this has been す all along. So this connection must be non-existent.

Comment: @aguijonazo, sorry, what do you mean by _"it seems this has been す all along"_?  What is "this" in your statement?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi - Sorry, I meant the ず of 引きずる. It seems it has never been written with つ unlike the ず of かけずる.

Comment: @aguijonazo, aha, now I'm with you!    Agreed.